# Google Play Games Broken - 100% Errors of Achievements and Leaderboard APIs

Tags: android, google-cloud-platform, google-play-games

There was an incident where my Google Play Games Services broke while integrating Google Firebase into my game. Somehow I fixed it by adding SHA-1 fingerprints of both uploading & app signing certificates, but achievements and the leaderboard system still don't work anymore.

The authentication works, and also saved games work. I recently found this stuff from the Google Cloud console, and it seems like calling achievement, and leaderboard API fail 100%.

What should I check to fix this?

[image]

Comment: Hello! Same problem. Did you solve it?

Comment: @ИльинПавел Unfortunately no. Even developers don't answer it. Have no idea what to do.